# Importing messy data to r

Tags: r

```
 Lake Elsinore  9.7 F W 60.2 131 1 1 0 2310.1
 Lake Elsinore  10.4 F W 53.9 67 0 0 0 1815.9
 Lake Elsinore  10.1 M W 54.3 96 1 1 1 1872.9
 Lake Elsinore  9.6 M W 55.1 72 1 . 1 1980.4
```

So here I have ten variables V1-V10. How can I read it to R. You see the first variable is actually separated by space. So I can't read in "separating by space". Could someone have me to find a way that I could easily import those kind of data in. 
Thank you so so much!

Comment: I would read it with space as separator and then modify the data

Comment: Is the first column always composed of two words?

Comment: Might be best to `readLines`, then wrap quotes around the city names for the first column, just in case there are multiple words.  Then you can use `read.table(text = ...)` on that text

Comment: @nico actually no. It's a location variable. It can be for example "Lake Elsinore" or "Riverside" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

**1)** It could be done with `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package.  The matches to the parenthesized portions of the pattern are read in as separate fields:

```
library(gsubfn)

pattern <- "^(.*) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+)" 
read.pattern("myfile.dat", pattern, na.strings = ".")
```

giving:

```
                 V1   V2 V3 V4   V5  V6 V7 V8 V9    V10
1     Lake Elsinore  9.7  F  W 60.2 131  1  1  0 2310.1
2     Lake Elsinore 10.4  F  W 53.9  67  0  0  0 1815.9
3     Lake Elsinore 10.1  M  W 54.3  96  1  1  1 1872.9
4     Lake Elsinore  9.6  M  W 55.1  72  1 NA  1 1980.4
```

**2)**  Read in the lines as they are, replace the first space on each line with some character (here we use underscore), re-read it now using `read.table` and then replace the underscore with space:

```
L <- readLines("myfile.dat")
L <- sub(" ", "_", L)
DF <- read.table(text = L, na.strings = ".")
DF[[1]] <- sub("_", " ", DF[[1]])
```

giving the same answer.

Comment: @CharoletteDeng 1) will work with 1, 2, 3, or more words for V1--really nice; 2) not as robust but will still work in the sample data

Answer (score 1):

It's a little clunky, but I usually just read it in raw and parse the data from there. You could do something like:

```
# First, read in all columns space separated
df <- read.table(FILE, header = F, sep = " ")

# Create a new column (V12) that's a concatenation of V1, V2
within(df, V12 <- paste(V1, V2, sep=' '))

# And then drop the unwanted columns
df <- df[,2:11]
```

Remember, you have 11 columns reading it in raw, which is why I'm creating a 12th.